# How to resume from the hibernate Image in android

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I would seek some help if my understanding in resume from the hibernate image from SD card in the android file-system.

I have created the hibernate image in the SD card by below commands:

```
    # makeswap /dev/block/mmcblk1
    # swapon /dev/block/mmcblk1
    # echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

and also added in the kernel `bootargs resume=/dev/block/mmcblk1`

It writes the images to SD card, but while booting the image it boot normally 
and when i added the printk for debugging purpose.

```
In kernel/power/hibernate.c
Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    8.466894] ********* 726: software_resume
[    8.470645] ********PM: Hibernation image partition 0:0 present
```

Is my understanding wrong , or I am doing some mistakes,anyone can tell me,thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that mmcblk1 is a swap partition ?